# What is the difference when a request is made to an open redirect vulnerable url though a browser and through the server using ssrf?

Tags: ssrf

There is a url `abc.com/something` vulnerable to open redirect to `xyz.com` (fixed)

I am catching requests at `xyz.com` to see contents of requests coming to it.

1. When I browse `abc.com/something` (being logged in to `abc.com`) from a browser, then the content that I catch at `xyz.com` doesn't have any session_cookie of `abc.com`.
2. Now there is a url `abc.com/path=<redirect_url>` in abc.com which calls internal abc apis. So if `abc.com?path=/something/` is called, then `abc.com` server calls `abc.com/something`. Since it is vulnerable to open redirect, so when I call it, I see the `session_id` of `abc.com` in my request catcher at xyz.com.

So what is the difference between these two types of call? In both the cases redirection to xyz.com is happening from abc.com. Only difference is initiator of request in first its browser, in second its the server itself. In both the cases, I think it is a whitelisted(or blacklisted) domain that is making call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case the browser is making the call to the attackers domain. Since a cookie is bound to the origin domain it will not be *implicitly* included in the request to the *different* attackers domain.

In the second case the server side application *explicitly* includes the session_id in all requests since the application *assumes* that the given URL points to an internal API endpoint. It will therefore also *explicitly* include the session_id to requests to the attackers domain.